# Loop in a specific list to define class options

Tags: babel, loops, key-value, right-to-left, class-options

I have a class `beamer-rl` to create beamer presentation for RTL languages (like persian) and I need a way to include RTL language as a class option like this `\documentclass[persian]{beamer-rl}`

So class will test if `persian` is in a list of RTL languages let's say, for example :`{arabic,arabic-DZ,arabic-MA,persian,hebrew,....}` then command will be processed

```
\AddToHook{env/document/before}{\babelprovide[import,main]{#1}} % #1 will hold persian
```

And the final result is a class where the user can add the RTL main language as option of the class like this

```
\documentclass[persian]{beamer-rl} % or arabic, hebrew, ...
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{}
سلام
\end{fram}
\end{document}
```

The class file starts as follows

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{beamer-rl}
[2022/12/17 v1.7  LaTeX class to patch beamer for right to left presentation with babel]

\RequirePackage{kvoptions}
\RequirePackage{kvsetkeys}

\SetupKeyvalOptions{
    family=beamer-rl,
    prefix=beamer-rl@,
    setkeys=\kvsetkeys,
}

% babel options:
\define@key{beamer-rl}{babel}{%
    \PassOptionsToPackage{#1}{babel}%
}

DeclareDefaultOption{%
    \PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{beamer}%
}

\ProcessKeyvalOptions*\relax

\RequirePackage{ifluatex}

\ifluatex
\else
\ClassError{beamer-rl}{beamer-rl require lualatex}
\fi

\LoadClass[hyperref={unicode}]{beamer}

\RequirePackage[nil,bidi=basic]{babel}
```

For a single option (language) I can define it with

```
 \DeclareVoidOption{persian}{%
        \AddToHook{env/document/before}{\babelprovide[import,main]{persian}}}
```

But things do not work out when using `\@for` loop with a `Missing \endcsname inserted` error

```
\def\langlist{arabic,arabic-MA,arabic-DZ,persian,hebrew}
\@for \next:=\langlist\do{%
\DeclareVoidOption{\next}{%
\AddToHook{env/document/before}{\babelprovide[import,main]{\next}}}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you don't want to change the used package for your options. Nowadays I'd choose either the built-in mechanism of LaTeX2e/`expl3` with `\ProcessKeyOptions` or `expkv-opt` (of which I'm the author). Anyway your issue with `\@for` is that you need to expand `\next`, which the following would do.

```
\newcommand*\langlist{arabic,arabic-MA,arabic-DZ,persian,hebrew}
\@for \next:=\langlist\do
  {%
    \expanded{\noexpand\DeclareVoidOption{\next}
      {%
        \noexpand\AddToHook{env/document/before}%
          {\noexpand\babelprovide[import,main]{\next}}%
      }}%
  }
```

However, I'd suggest not using `\@for` in this case but the way easier to correctly use `\clist_map_inline:nn`:

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_map_inline:nn {arabic,arabic-MA,arabic-DZ,persian,hebrew}
  {
    \DeclareVoidOption{#1}{
      \AddToHook{env/document/before}{\babelprovide[import,main]{#1}}}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Your complete minimal class file would then be:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{beamer-rl}
[2022/12/17 v1.7  LaTeX class to patch beamer for right to left presentation with babel]

\RequirePackage{kvoptions}
\RequirePackage{kvsetkeys}

\SetupKeyvalOptions{
    family=beamer-rl,
    prefix=beamer-rl@,
    setkeys=\kvsetkeys,
}

% babel options:
\define@key{beamer-rl}{babel}{\PassOptionsToPackage{#1}{babel}}

\DeclareDefaultOption{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{beamer}}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_map_inline:nn {arabic,arabic-MA,arabic-DZ,persian,hebrew}
  {
    \DeclareVoidOption{#1}{
      \AddToHook{env/document/before}{\babelprovide[import,main]{#1}}}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\ProcessKeyvalOptions*\relax

\RequirePackage{ifluatex}

\ifluatex
\else
\ClassError{beamer-rl}{beamer-rl require lualatex}
\fi

\LoadClass[hyperref={unicode}]{beamer}

\RequirePackage[nil,bidi=basic]{babel}
```

---

## Using LaTeX2e's built-in mechanism

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{beamer-rl}
[2022/12/17 v1.7  LaTeX class to patch beamer for right to left presentation with babel]

\DeclareKeys
  {
     babel   .code:n = \PassOptionsToPackage{#1}{babel}
    ,unknown .code:n = \PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{beamer}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_map_inline:nn {arabic,arabic-MA,arabic-DZ,persian,hebrew}
  {
    \DeclareKeys
      {
         #1 .code:n = 
          \AddToHook{env/document/before}{\babelprovide[import,main]{#1}}
        ,#1 .value_forbidden:n = true
      }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\ProcessKeyOptions

\RequirePackage{ifluatex}

\ifluatex
\else
\ClassError{beamer-rl}{beamer-rl require lualatex}
\fi

\LoadClass[hyperref={unicode}]{beamer}

\RequirePackage[nil,bidi=basic]{babel}
```

---

## Using `expkv-opt`

Example file using `expkv-def` and `expkv-opt` (the shown `\ekvoProcessOptions` is part of a not yet released version but I estimate that to happen in the next few days, you can use `\ekvoProcessGlobalOptions` and `\ekvoProcessLocalOptions` instead).

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{beamer-rl}
[2022/12/17 v1.7  LaTeX class to patch beamer for right to left presentation with babel]

\RequirePackage{expkv-def,expkv-opt}

\ekvdefinekeys{beamer-rl}
  {
     code    babel = \PassOptionsToPackage{#1}{babel}
    ,unknown code  = \PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{beamer}
    ,unknown noval = \PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{beamer}
  }
% expkv has its own csv-loop, but you could still use \clist_map_inline:nn
% instead
\def\beamerRL@tmp#1
  {%
    \ekvdefNoVal{beamer-rl}{#1}%
      {\AddToHook{env/document/before}{\babelprovide[import,main]{#1}}}%
  }
\ekvcsvloop\beamerRL@tmp{arabic,arabic-MA,arabic-DZ,persian,hebrew}
\ekvoUseUnknownHandlers*
\ekvoProcessOptions{beamer-rl}

\RequirePackage{ifluatex}

\ifluatex
\else
\ClassError{beamer-rl}{beamer-rl require lualatex}
\fi

\LoadClass[hyperref={unicode}]{beamer}

\RequirePackage[nil,bidi=basic]{babel}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, please another request can you explain what changes we should make if we removes `kvoptions` and `kvsetkeys` packages and use your  suggested methods (with LaTeX2e/expl3 and with   `expkv-opt` )

Comment: @SalimBou done.